# Restart a completed background job in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jobs

In PowerShell 5.1 I have created a background job with the below command

```
Start-Job { while($true) { Get-Random; Start-Sleep 5 } } -Name Sleeper
```

The job gets created fine and it returns the results with `Receive-Job` as well. And I stopped it with `Stop-Job` cmdlet.

And I would like to restart it again in the same PS session.

I execute `Get-Job` cmdlet and I see the job there in the Stopped state.

How to restart it without recreating it?

I could not get this information in about_Jobs.

The script block is just a sample script. I am more interested to know if there is a way to restart the already existing job.

Comment: Try `Get-Help *JOB` and see if  you can resume using `Resume-Job`

Comment: Seems Resume-Job is to resume suspended jobs. Getting the error "Resuming jobs is not supported for some job types. For more information about support for resuming jobs, see the Help topic for the job type."

Comment: You want to run the same job to completion, multiple times, correct?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes.. Without recreating it if possible..

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that, you'll have to recreate it. Could you maybe explain *why* you want to run (and restart) an endless loop inside a background job? There might be a better solution to whatever you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Well if there exists a job already in stopped state why shoudn't be a way to just restart it? I do not have a business requirement for this at the moment. The script is just a sample script. I would have a fruitful script later.

Comment: If you want the job to continue, why would you stop it in the first place? For temporarily pausing a job use `Suspend-Job`, so you can later `Resume-Job`. That's what the cmdlets are for.

Comment: If the command completes its job then the state of the job would already be complete..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot re-run completed jobs. One thing you could do is start a new job from the command of the completed one:

```
$j1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ... }
...
$j2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($j1.Command))
```

If you need something that you can re-run at will you probably want a scheduled task or a [scheduled job](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job/):

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At '2:00 PM'
$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -StartIfOnBattery -StartIfIdle
Register-ScheduledJob -Name 'myjob' -ScriptBlock { ... } -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options
```

and (re-)invoke it e.g. like this:

```
(Get-ScheduledJob -Name 'myjob').StartJob()
```